# Problem with function to generate a DXF with a MTEXT

Tags: excel, autocad, dxf, vba7

I'm working on an Excel spreadsheet to generate a DXF. So far I've been able to generate a function for lines, polylines, polygons, circles and simple text but I'm struggling to code a `MTEXT` function.

This is what I have at this point:

```vb
Function DXF_MTEXTO(ByRef DXF_TEXT As String, ByVal CAPA As String, _
               ByVal CX As Single, ByVal CY As Single, ByVal 
miTexto As String, _
               ByVal miAltura As Single, ByVal ang As Single) As String

DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf            'Entidad
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "MTEXT" & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 100 & vbCrLf          'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "AcDbEntity" & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 100 & vbCrLf          'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "AcDbMText" & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 8 & vbCrLf            'Capa
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CAPA & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 10 & vbCrLf           'Coordenada X del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CX & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 20 & vbCrLf           'Coordenada Y del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CY & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 1 & vbCrLf            'Texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miTexto & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 40 & vbCrLf           'Altura de texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miAltura & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 41 & vbCrLf           ' Ancho de rectángulo de referencia
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 16 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 71 & vbCrLf           ' Punto de anclaje: 1 Top Left
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 1 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 72 & vbCrLf           ' Dirección del texto: 5 By Style
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 5 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 50 & vbCrLf           ' Rotación del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & ang & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 90 & vbCrLf           ' Background fill: 0 = Off
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf

DXF_MTEXTO = DXF_TEXT
End Function
```

Could anybody please give me a hand? A piece of code, a reference (Different from AutoDesk DXF reference)

Thanks in advance!

I read the DXF references and tried to modify the other functions thinking it would work according to AutoDesk pdf.

For example, this is the function (It works pretty fine) for simple text:

This is the code I use for the begining of the file:

```vb
Function DXF_INICIO(ByRef DXF_TEXT As String) As String
    DXF_TEXT = 0 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "SECTION" & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 2 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "ENTITIES" & vbCrLf

    DXF_INICIO = DXF_TEXT
End Function
```

This is the code I use for the end of the file:

```vb
Function DXF_FINAL(ByRef DXF_TEXT As String) As String
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "ENDSEC" & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "EOF" & vbCrLf

    DXF_FINAL = DXF_TEXT
End Function
```

This is the code I use for the simple text (And it works pretty fine)

```vb
Function DXF_TEXTO(ByRef DXF_TEXT As String, ByVal CAPA As String, _
                   ByVal CX As Single, ByVal CY As Single, ByVal miTexto As String, _
                   ByVal miAltura As Single, ByVal ang As Single) As String

    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "TEXT" & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 8 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CAPA & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 10 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CX & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 20 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CY & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 1 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miTexto & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 40 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miAltura & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 50 & vbCrLf
    DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & ang & vbCrLf
    
    DXF_TEXTO = DXF_TEXT
End Function
```

This is the error I got when using the `MTEXT` function:

> Undefined group code 10 for object on line XX.
> Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.

This is what the DXF looks like:

```
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
POLYLINE
8
001-WALL
66
1
70
1
0
VERTEX
8
001-WALL
70
1
10
3.4742
20
18.7913
0
VERTEX
8
001-WALL
70
1
10
6.0183
20
18.7913
0
VERTEX
8
001-WALL
70
1
10
6.0183
20
19.4579
0
VERTEX
8
001-WALL
70
1
10
3.4742
20
19.4579
0
SEQEND
0
MTEXT
100
AcDbEntity
100
AcDbMText
8
000-TEXT
10
6.079583
20
20.45793
1
#5@48"\PL: 2.55ft t: 8"\PVu: 3 kip\PVu/Vn: 40%
40
0.25
41
16
71
1
72
5
50
0
90
0
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

Comment: I assume you have created a `MTEXT` item in Autocad (or similar) and dxf'ed it out and compared the differences? And I assume you have read the official breakdown of a `MTEXT` entity?https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-5E5DB93B-F8D3-4433-ADF7-E92E250D2BAB

Comment: Yes sir, I did read it.

I just cant figure out what's wrong in my code.

I think I'm missing some extra info in the headers, not in the MTEXT parte, per se.

Comment: I created an empty R12 DXF and pasted in your entities and then tried to open that DXF. This is the message: "No database handle specified for object on line 1200.
Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded." Line 1200 is for the first vertex. So I would start there. I believe you are missing a group 5 value with is a handle. LIke I suggested, create a polyline and mtext in Autocad and dxfout as R12. Then do a diff on the entities section. You need handles it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`MTEXT` entities require that you specify subclass markers, e.g.:

```vb
Function DXF_MTEXTO(ByRef DXF_TEXT As String, ByVal CAPA As String, _
               ByVal CX As Single, ByVal CY As Single, ByVal miTexto As String, _
               ByVal miAltura As Single, ByVal ang As Single) As String

DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf            'Entidad
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "MTEXT" & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 100 & vbCrLf          'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "AcDbEntity" & vbCrLf 'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 100 & vbCrLf          'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & "AcDbMText" & vbCrLf  'Subclass marker
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 8 & vbCrLf            'Capa
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CAPA & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 10 & vbCrLf           'Coordenada X del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CX & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 20 & vbCrLf           'Coordenada Y del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & CY & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 1 & vbCrLf            'Texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miTexto & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 40 & vbCrLf           'Altura de texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & miAltura & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 41 & vbCrLf           ' Ancho de rectángulo de referencia
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 16 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 71 & vbCrLf           ' Punto de anclaje: 1 Top Left
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 1 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 72 & vbCrLf           ' Dirección del texto: 5 By Style
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 5 & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 50 & vbCrLf           ' Rotación del texto
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & ang & vbCrLf
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 90 & vbCrLf           ' Background fill: 0 = Off
DXF_TEXT = DXF_TEXT & 0 & vbCrLf

DXF_MTEXTO = DXF_TEXT
End Function
```

You may also need to define some header variables, else without this information AutoCAD will assume that the DXF is targeting R12 in which the MText entity did not exist.

Try adding the following at the start of the file:

```
0
SECTION
2
HEADER
9
$ACADVER
1
AC1032
0
ENDSEC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use it but I got this error when opening the DXF file:
Undefined group code 10 for object on line 14.
Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.

Comment: Thanks, Lee Mac.

I updated again the code and added the full DXF. I'm still having issues with it.